# Получение данных из модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня такой вопрос: требуется, чтобы при нажатии по ссылке, открывалось модальное окно с открытой отдельной страницей, на которой изображены формы для ввода. Далее после ввода данных в формы, при нажатии ОК данные должны отобразиться в родительской странице (с которой запускали модальное окно) без обновления страницы. Как это возможно сделать?

Сейчас пользуюсь Модальными окнами на JQuery ColorBox и Twitter Bootstrap Modal Contact Form, но получилось только выводить информацию, если код модального окна написан в одном файле с родительским.

Comment: Данные нужно просто продублировать в инпутах или должен создаться новый объект html с этими данными?

Comment: для начала хотя бы просто продублировать

Comment: Если элементы модального окна уже находятся на странице, то можете сразу при старте слушать изменение на нужных вам инпутах и вставлять введенное значения туда, куда вам нужно, например:

$("input[name='length']").change(function (event) {
  var self = $(this);
  console.log('change',  self.val());
  $("input[name='length-two']").val(self.val());
});

Comment: Либо собирать данные после закрытия модального окна.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я еще новичек в этом деле, поэтому могу задать глупые вопросы, но подскажите, пожалуйста: length и length-two - это имена форм в модальной окне и родительском соответственно? или я что-то не так понял. И как организовать вызов этого скрипта с модального окна? Еще раз извиняюсь, если туплю) И это будет работать, если модальное окно открывает другую страницу?

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли. Открывает другую страницу, что вы под этим подразумеваете, что тело модального окна откуда-то загружается с помощью ajax?  Если нет и тело модального окна присутствует постоянно на странице, но только скрыто от пользователя. То скрипт можно инициализировать при загрузке странице, так как все элементы присутствуют на странице и ошибки их выбора из dom дерева не будет.

Comment: говоря "открывает другую страницу" я имею ввиду, что код, который загружается в модальном окне берется не из этого же html файла, а открывается другая html страница.

Comment: В контексте одной вкладки браузера? Используете модальное окно twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Не понял как это " в контексте одной вкладки браузера". Пробовал и с twitter bootstrap и colorbox (http://kcoding.net/2012/jquery-colorbox-modalwindow/). Работает только если код указан в этом же html файле, а как вынести его в другую страницу, не могу разобраться.

Comment: До этого использовали windows.open и было все замечательно, но сейчас он работает только в IE. Возможно есть какое-то решение?

Comment: Я так понял страница загружается в iframe) Если так, то при открытии модального окна вешаете событие полной загрузки iframe, затем внутри iframe уже ищите нужные инпуты и собираете с них значения.